# How to properly hide a method

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
struct A {
    void f() { g(); }
private:
    void g() {std::cout << "A.g" << std::endl;}
};

struct B: A {
    // Inherited f from A, but I want f to call B.g this time.
private:
    void g() {std::cout << "B.g" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    B{}.f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is `A.g`. Is there a way to make it output `B.g` without making `g` virtual?

Comment: Do not use inheritance, but composition: `struct B { private: A a; };`

Comment: @DieterLücking Any other way? Inheritance is the natural way to think about the actual classes (well, structs) in question.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a virtual?

Comment: You can use the CRTP. But honestly, why not make it virtual? If `B` *really*  is an `A`...

Comment: What's wrong with making `g()` virtual?

Comment: @DanRoche This will degrade performance of a critical part of the library I am writing.

Comment: One way would be to add the line "void f() { g(); }" into the struct B class also

Comment: In short, no. You need some way to tell `A` that you want it to call another implementation of `g()`. Either use `virtual` or do it manually via a function pointer.

Comment: *"This will degrade performance..."* You bench-marked that?

Comment: @StoryTeller Accepted your criticism.

Comment: @DieterLücking Does that have any relevance to answering the question, or is it just a mantra that people repeat anywhere they get the slightest pretext?

Comment: @underscore_d No mantra,  From my point of view `struct A`  is a logically sealed (final) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to avoid run-time polymorphism using `virtual`, I think things will have to get a bit more verbose.

The **basic solution** would be to simply repeat the definition of `f()` within `B`:

```
struct A {
    void f() { g(); }
private:
    void g() {std::cout << "A.g" << std::endl;}
};

struct B: A {
    void f() { g(); } // will bind to B.g in this context
private:
    void g() {std::cout << "B.g" << std::endl;}
};
```

But this may be undesirable from a software engineering standpoint and the DRY principle. If there's some functionality within `f()` besides just calling `g()`, you will have two copies of that functionality in your code, which is bad.

In most situations like this, **you can avoid polymorphism by using templates**, but the code gets a bit uglier. Here's one way to do that, where the member functions `g()` are put into structs, the original `f()` is made to be a template member function, and there is a simple duplicated definition of `f()` for convenience:

```
class A {
  private:
    struct G {
      void operator()() { std::cout << "A.g" << std::endl; }
    };
  protected:
    template <typename gfun> void ffun() { 
      gfun()(); 
      /* (maybe some other common functionality in here too) */
    }
  public:
    void f() { ffun<G>(); }
};

class B :public A {
  private:
    struct G {
      void operator()() { std::cout << "B.g" << std::endl; }
    };
  public:
    void f() { ffun<G>(); }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.f(); // prints "A.g"
  B b;
  b.f(); // prints "B.g"
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The basic solution" to the question "How to properly hide a method" is to use the pattern that's literally called _hiding_ - who'd have thought? ;-) About your template idea, does that offer any benefit over CRTP? It seems to do the same thing but while being a lot less idiomatic/intuitive.

Comment: I actually like this last one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your call pattern (ie, invoke `f()` only via an indirect call to `g()`), and you need runtime polymorphism, then you basically need to declare f() to be `virtual`. After all, that's the exact use case for a virtual function.

If all you need is compile time polymorphism, you could consider using the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but the potential performance gain that you might get from that does come at the expense of code readability. Unless you can prove that the overhead of an indirect call via the virtual table is expensive enough to make it worth the trade-off of attempting to be smarter than the compiler, readability and correctness win in my book.

There are rare cases where the runtime cost of a virtual call actually matters, but unless the environment you work in requires you to squeeze the last nanosecond out of the code (and there are very, very few fields where this is actually necessary), it won't matter to you.